# MDT and Powershell

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, deployment, windows-server-2012-r2, mdt

[image: Error Message]
[image: Permissions]
[image: Setup]

I've checked the path names and they are correct. I've tried editing the permissions and they seem fine.

What else should I try?

EDIT:

I also tried this way:
http://damonjohns.com/2014/03/12/removing-windows-8-1-modern-applications-during-your-mdt-sccm-task-sequence/

I don't get the screen but the script does not seem to be copying the ps1 files over to execute them.

My Script:

```
powershell.exe -Command “set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force; cpi ‘%DEPLOYROOT%\Applications\SCRIPT - Enable Remote Managament By Opening Firewall Rules\script_enable_remote_management_open_firewall_rules.ps1′ -destination c:\; c:\script_enable_remote_management_open_firewall_rules.ps1"
```

**EDIT:
Everytime I check C:\ I do not see my rules copied over. I have also now had everything go thru without getting a FAILURE screen but I do not see the scripts and do not see them executed.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run power shell scripts you will need to add it as a Task Sequence item. You can do this by adding the `Run PowerShell Script` entry into your Task Sequence.

Make sure that you add it after the system has restarted from installing/applying the image.

[image: How to add into task sequence.]

In the task configuration you will need to point to the ps1 file that houses your commands. You may be able to execute a single command (I am not sure).

Comment: Hey, yes, I tried that with no success. ;/

Comment: It looks like you also need to add `.net  framework`, `DISM Cmdlets` and `Enhanced storage`. I will update the picture if that works. I had forgot to put that in :-P

Comment: No luck. What do you use for a CLI in your Task Sequence to get the system to run PS Scripts?

Comment: Did you update your deployment share images?

Comment: I would personally recommend to rebuild the images completely.

Comment: Yes, I always do full rebuilds.

Comment: In your task sequence are you adding the `run power shell script` entry?

Comment: I just dug this up, check it out:http://scriptimus.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/ltizti-powershell-using-powershell-in-task-sequences/
It should solve your power shell issue. Plus this guy also helps to make a ZTI environment with MDT.

Comment: I'll try that. I just noticed a comment about GPO that restricts PS on a domain level. I'll try disabling that. Maybe that has an effect.

Comment: OK. Keep me posted

Comment: As far as I know that was probably the issue. The other thing I noticed was that I also was trying to do the scripts as an application.

Comment: Did you try running the scripts as a powershell script? (Task Sequence)
I will revise the answer based on your reply

Comment: What I did was is I set them up as an Application: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2nuua6a.jpg then I add an application and link to that script from within the Task Sequence. (basically going for the idea to be able to select and run what scripts that I want. now if I don't do it as an application and just link to the script as a powershell script options from within Task sequence, it works.). Thanks for your help and time. I recently moved to this topic now: http://serverfault.com/questions/610710/running-powershell-scripts-as-an-application-in-mdt-2013

Comment: Thanks, I will update the answer to this question for other people :)